# Where could I find Workout app on the Apple Watch simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, watchos

Maybe it's very simple but I'm really in stuck. I want to try the new WorkoutKit introduced in WatchOS 10. I run iPhone 15 simulator (iOS 17) and paired Apple Watch (WatchOS 10). In the watch settings I could see Workout section, but there is no Workout app in the app list.
Thank you in advance.